# System level app/UI in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to develop system level UI for Android? An example would be in the home screen as the user touches and drags to move between pages, custom cursor/visualization (such as particle system) occur under the finger/stylus.

I know how to do this at the app level, but not at the system/OS level. Any directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do u mean a live wallpaper (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) or a custom launcher (http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/) ??

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom Launcher... That's just like programming an app.

Comment: Thank you! I will read up custom launchers and get back.